# Putting an EXE and a DLL together in VS 2013

Tags: c++, dll, exe, dllimport, dllexport

I have a solution put together in VS 2013, but I'm getting various errors in the link process:

"error lnk2019: unresolved external symbol"

"error LNK1104: cannot open file 'VoIPDLL.lib'"

This all seems to be related to which directory VS2013 is trying to link in. I did the walkthrough at:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636%28v=vs.120%29.aspx

And that worked. However, what I'm doing now is not working. I have a separate directory for the EXE and the DLL (which is what the walkthrough did).

Where does VS2013 look for data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add path to directory containing VoIPDLL.lib at project's context menu: "Properties" -> "Configuration Properties" -> "Linker" -> "General" -> "Additional Library Directories"

Comment: I'm not finding this in the properties window ""Configuration Properties" -> "General" -> "Additional Library Directories". Can you explain?

Comment: look at the screenshot: http://www.steptools.com/support/stdev_docs/help/images/vc10_libpath.gif

Comment: OK, you are talking about the menu item Project-><name of project> Properties-> "Configuration Properties" -> "Linker" -> "General" -> "Additional Library Directories". That makes sense. I'll give it a try later today and mark this as the correct answer if it works.